# Lumen Laravel decouple business logic

Tags: laravel, business-logic, lumen

How/where to decouple business logic under lumen, away from the controller a preferably away from "app/http" directory.

Answer (score 1):

After searching the internet for a clean conclusive way to decouple my business logic, I decided to start experimenting. For me, the following works like a charm.

Create a new directory under "app\Objects". Keep in mind that i've chosen to name mine "Objects" as my personal preference, feel free to name it whatever suits you.

My new file seats under "app\Objects\testObject.php" for this example:

```
namespace App\Objects;

class testObject
{
    public function businessLogicTest ()
    {        
        // some database calls would go here

        // response here
        return 'This is some business logic response';
    }
}
```

Then under your "app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php" add the following "use App\Objects\testObject" and then instantiate your logic:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Objects\testObject;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function helloWorld ()
    {
      $test = new testObject();
      echo $test->businessLogicTest();    
    }
}
```

Once you're happy with your directory structure proceed to use database usage under your new business logic layer. Hope it helps :-)